# Why is this happening?Who can give me the answer

Tags: npm-install

installing problem

PS C:\Users\Administrator> gatsby new gatsby-site3
info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
Cloning into 'gatsby-site3'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 54, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (54/54), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (34/34), done.
remote: Total 1578 (delta 39), reused 35 (delta 20), pack-reused 1524
Receiving objects: 100% (1578/1578), 5.71 MiB | 149.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (954/954), done.
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...

> sharp@0.21.3 install C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp
>   (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_libvips\libvips-8.7.0-win32-x64.tar.gz
info sharp Creating C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
info sharp Copying DLLs from C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp\vendor\lib to C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=12.1.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 13, in 
    import gyp
  File "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp__init__.py", line 7, in 
    import copy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\copy.py", line 52, in 
    import weakref
  File "C:\Python27\lib\weakref.py", line 14, in 
    from _weakref import (
ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Administrator\gatsby-site3\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-01T09_34_10_497Z-debug.log
error Command failed: npm install

Error: Command failed: npm install

- index.js:236
  [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:236:11
- task_queues.js:89 processTicksAndRejections
  internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5

Answer (score 1):

The Gatsby packages currently are using slightly older versions of `sharp`. This will resolve itself when the Gatsby developers are upgrading their dependencies and ship new releases that depend upon the latest versions.

Three options I would suggest:

1. Downgrade to at least Node 11 (I suggest looking into [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm))
2. If you are using yarn use the resolutions feature in yarn in your package.json:

```
{
  "resolutions": {
    "sharp": "0.22.1"
  }
}
```

3. Wait for new releases that depend on the latest versions